# Añadir varios item de un articulo

Tags: php, session

Tengo el siguiente código y quiero añadir varias unidades de un producto o item.

```
<?php
session_start();

class Product {

    private $productId;
    private $productName;
    private $price;
    private $cantidad;


    public function __construct($productId, $productName, $price, $cantidad) {
        $this->productId = $productId;
        $this->productName = $productName;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->cantidad = $cantidad;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->productId;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->productName;
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function getCantidad(){
        return $this->cantidad;
    }

}

$products = array(
    1 => new Product(1, "SuperWidget", 19.99, 1),
    2 => new Product(2, "MegaWidget", 29.99, 1),
    3 => new Product(3, "WonderWidget", 39.99, 1),
    4 => new Product(4, "Producto añadido 1", 69.99, 1),
    5 => new Product(5, "Producto añadido 2", 89.99, 1)
);

if (!isset($_SESSION["cart"]))
    $_SESSION["cart"] = array();

if (isset($_GET["action"]) and $_GET["action"] == "addItem") {
    addItem();
} elseif (isset($_GET["action"]) and $_GET["action"] == "removeItem") {
    removeItem();
} else {
    displayCart();
}

function addItem() {
    global $products;
    if (isset($_GET["productId"]) and $_GET["productId"] >= 1 and $_GET["productId"] <= 5) {
        $productId = (int) $_GET["productId"];

        if (!isset($_SESSION["cart"][$productId])) {
            $_SESSION["cart"][$productId] = $products[$productId];
        }
    }

    session_write_close();
    header("Location: index.php");
}

function removeItem() {
    global $products;
    if (isset($_GET["productId"]) and $_GET["productId"] >= 1 and $_GET["productId"] <= 5) {
        $productId = (int) $_GET["productId"];

        if (isset($_SESSION["cart"][$productId])) {
            unset($_SESSION["cart"][$productId]);
        }
    }

    session_write_close();
    header("Location: index.php");
}

function displayCart() {
    global $products;
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>A shopping cart using sessions</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
        </head>
        <body>

            <h1>Your shopping cart</h1>
            <dl>
                <?php
                $totalPrice = 0;
                foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $product) {
                    $totalPrice += $product->getPrice()* $product->getCantidad();
                    ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $product->getName() ?></dt>
                    <dd>$<?php echo number_format($product->getPrice(), 2) ?> x
                        <?php echo $product->getCantidad() ?> uds.
                        <a href="index.php?action=removeItem&amp;productId=<?php echo $product->getId() ?>">Remove</a> </dd>
                <?php } ?>
                <dt>Cart Total:</dt>
                <dd><strong>$<?php echo number_format($totalPrice, 2) ?></strong></dd>
            </dl>

            <h1>Product list</h1>
            <dl>
            <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $product->getName() ?></dt>
                    <dd>$<?php echo number_format($product->getPrice(), 2) ?>
                        <a href="index.php?action=addItem&amp;productId=<?php echo $product->getId() ?>">Add Item</a></dd>
            <?php } ?>
            </dl>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahora sólo añade un único producto. He creado un valor en el array para contabilizar las unidades, pero no sé tratarlo para que al pulsar me añada unidades y no el producto.

Comment: ¿Por qué igualas la sesión de "cart" a un array vacío?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Agregar a la clase `Product` un nuevo método `addCantidad`:

  ```
  class Product {

      // Todo lo anterior más el nuevo método

      public function addCantidad(){
          $this->cantidad++;
      }
  }
  ```

  **Nota:** Si fuera necesario, se podría pasar por parámetro la cantidad a sumar
- Modificar la función `addItem`:

  ```
  function addItem() {
      global $products;
      if (isset($_GET["productId"]) and $_GET["productId"] >= 1 and $_GET["productId"] <= 5) {
          $productId = (int) $_GET["productId"];

          // Si no esta, lo agregamos
          if (!isset($_SESSION["cart"][$productId])) {
              $_SESSION["cart"][$productId] = $products[$productId];
          }
          // Si ya esta, aumentamos la cantidad
          else {
              $_SESSION["cart"][$productId]->addCantidad();
         }
      }

      session_write_close();
      header("Location: index.php");
  }
  ```

Comment: Añadiendo estos que dices y puliendo un detalle, parece que funciona.
Ahora solo me falta revisar el método de elimnar, no quiero que me elimne el producte entero, si no solo un item.